# Resolving the Expression that Contains Variables in a Chart

Tags: qlikview

When I write an expression inside a chart in QlikView, and when that expression/formula contains variables, how can I see the actual values the chart is taking to calculate the expression? For example in the chapter 10. of the book **"QlikView for Developers"** there is the following variable `$($(=eMetric))`.

When I see the properties in the chart, this is all I see, although the variable, as it should, takes different values. How can I see the values this expression takes when evaluating it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adam,

There is no easy way to see it. But you can do the following trick:

Create a straight table with the same dimensions and expressions, or use the fast change to change your current chart to a straight table. Then remove the Title for the expression you wish to view the calculated result of. Close the properties.

Now when you hover you're mouse over where the title used to be you can see the evaluated results.

[image]